What is the requirement of setting the parameter robot_description in the parameter server?
I have just started using ROS and I was going through a few online tutorials. I understand that in order to visualize the robot in rviz plugin a parameter called robot_description is required to be loaded with URDF file. My question is

Is the parameter robot_description predefined and specific to rviz or just a convention?
If I want to load two different robots from two different URDF files, these two can be spawned in two separate namespaces. In that case, how rviz will identify these two robot_description in different namespaces?

